# Prove that $\mathbb{Z \times Z}/ \{(3m,n)\in\mathbb{Z \times Z}:m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z \times Z}$ be a ring, and $I=\{(3m,n)\in\mathbb{Z \times Z}:m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\} $, $J=\{(3m,0)\in\mathbb{Z \times Z}:m \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ two ideals of $R$. Prove that
>
> 1. $R/I$ is a field,
> 2. $R/J$ is not a field.

*My thought:*

1. $$ R/I = \mathbb{Z \times Z} / \langle3\rangle\times\mathbb{Z} \cong( \mathbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle) \times (\mathbb{Z / Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z_3} \times \{0\} \cong \mathbb{Z_3}$$ and the last one is a field, so $R/I$ is also a field.
2. $$R/J= \mathbb{Z \times Z} / \langle3\rangle\times\{0 \} \cong( \mathbb{Z}/\langle3\rangle) \times (\mathbb{Z}/ \{ 0\}) \cong \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z} $$ and the lastone is not a field, so$R/J$ is not a field.

Are these answers correct?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, i tried. I edited my question to show you my thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: If you can't succeed with what you tried, can you actually *identify* $R/I$ and $R/J$ explicitly as rings? You might use the fundamental homomorphism theorem to prove you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}
$$
defined by $(m,n)\mapsto m+3\mathbb{Z}$. What is its kernel? Is it surjective?

2) Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}
$$
defined by $(m,n)\mapsto (m+3\mathbb{Z},n)$. What is its kernel? Is it surjective?

Comment: If $φ:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/\langle 3 \rangle, (m,n)\mapsto φ(m,n)=m+3\mathbb{Z}$, then $φ$

 - Has $Kerφ=3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},$
 - $φ$ is well defined function and $φ$ is homomorphism,
 - $Imφ=\mathbb{Z}/ \langle3\rangle \iff$ $φ$ is surjective function.

So from the fundamental isomporhism theorem $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / \langle 3 \rangle \times \mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/\langle 3 \rangle$ and the last one is a field.

Comment: @Chris Yes, indeed But you get $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\ker\varphi\cong\mathbb{Z}/(3)$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, maybe parenthesis can help more... Thank you for your answer.